# Sasl connection refused

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

i am trying to run a selfhosted mailserver using postfix and dovecot.
firstly i configured only postfix without dovecot and that worked fine but i wanted to use a mail client so i installed dovecot to configure it. Now when i try to send and receive mail i get an error in postfix about SASL. First i get a warning aboutr connecting to private/auth failed:

```
Dec 14 12:50:56 debian postfix/smtpd[33959]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
```

after that i get a fatal error:

```
Dec 14 12:50:56 debian postfix/smtpd[33959]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

I tried reinstalling and re configuring everything but that also sadly did not help.
i tried following some online tutorials for setting this up:
[tutorial](https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/secure-postfix-using-lets-encrypt?unapproved=30412&moderation-hash=309e260d7356c3a58de5e645436b2be1#comment-30412)

If anyone has some advice it would be really appreciated.

dovecot version: 2.3.13 (89f716dc2)
mail_version = 3.5.18
running on debian 11

Comment: same issue did you find a solution?

Comment: No sorry I have given up

Comment: seems it happened due to expiration of ssl for me I renewed ssl and apply it for postfix then issue resolved.